# Unificationengine not working with instagram

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, unification, unificationengine

When I am sharing a message on instagram by **UnificationEngine** then I am getting this error:

```
Exception in UEUser.php line 74: The password you entered is incorrect. Please try again in UEUser.php line 74

at UEUser->add_connection('instagramBoard', 'instagram', '4544942713.7da612b.4de7a5a78fb0491dba2b27a60dc1749d') i
```

My Code is:

```
 $app = new UEApp("APP_KEY","APP_SECRATE");
 $user = new UEUser("USER_KEY", "USER_SECREATE");
 $con = $access_token ."@instagram.com/?username=rajneesh8239&password=testing1";
 $connection = $user->add_connection("instagramBoard", "instagram",   $con);
 $options = array(
      "receivers" => array(
            array(
                  "name"=> "Me"
             )
        ),
        "message"=>array(
            "subject"=>"Transparentcom testing fine",
             "body"=> "",
              "image"=> '',
               "link"=>array(
                   "uri"=> '',
                    "description"=> "",
                    "title"=>"Click here for view"
             )
          )
       );
 //Send the message and get their uris
 $uris = $connection->send_message($options);
```

CURL error:

vagrant@homestead:~/Code/laravel$ curl -XPOST https://apiv2.unificationengine.c
om/v2/user/create -u 590f402bd2a043f98823eb1940b2ab:a62c855ae17b5cacb355abfbcc3a93 --data '{}'
{"status":200,"info":"200 OK","uri":"user://0e4946b0-9e60-4e0f-b54-f4e39ab5b0b:0490d37c-e284-422e-b8de-00b5f81ff81@"}

vagrant@homestead:~/Code/laravel$ curl -XPOST https://apiv2.unificationengine.c
om/v2/connection/add -u 0e494b0-9e-4e0f-ab54-f4eab53b0b:04937c-e284-422e-b8de-003b5f81ff81 --data '{"uri":"instagram://4544942713.7da612b.4de7a5a78fb0491dba2b327a60dc1749d@instagram.com", "name":"instagram"}'
{"status":500,"info":"incorrect Password"}

Answer (score -1):

Please use this code like this way, You need to just change this line like this way.

```
$con = $access_token."@instagram.com/?username=rajneesh8239&password=testing1";
$connection = $user->add_connection("instagramBoard", "instagram", $con);
```

Please check with code